# SQL how to select all rows from table joining other table even if there are no rows associated

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables

```
Projects   Persons      PeopleInProjects
 - Id      - Id         - Id
 - Name    - Name       - PersonId
           - Role       - ProjectId
```

How would I select all Project names and Persons associated with that project where Persons Role is 'admin'?

PeopleInProjects is just a many to many relationship tables with Ids of all people associated with projects.
Projects can have many or none Persons associated with them.

I need to select all projects only once and I need to select projects even if they don't have a Person with Role 'admin' associated with them.

```
Select pr.Name, p.Name 
from Projects as pr 
join PeopleInProjects as pp on pr.Id = pp.ProjectId
join Persons as p on pp.PersonId = p.Id
Where p.Role = 'admin'
```

Only selects the Projects which have an admin associated with them and not all projects

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all projects *and then* any admins that might happen to be assigned, use `left join`:

```
Select pr.Name, p.Name 
from Projects pr left join
     (PeopleInProjects pp join
      Persons p
      on pp.PersonId = p.Id and p.Role = 'admin' 
     )
     on pr.Id = pp.ProjectId ;
```

Comment: That selects all Persons associated with the project and not only the ones that have 'admin' as their role thus selecting projects multiple times

Comment: @Martynas . . . I see.  This is one of those complicated situations.  The version with parentheses should do what you want.